# spatio-temporal precipitation prediction (python)

Tags: python, regression, spatial, prediction, temporal

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to make a GUI which shows the predicted precipitation values on a map for a half-hour timeframe. The data are in a folder in txt files. Each file contains measurements that are taken every fifteen minutes and contains the longitude, the latitude and the precipitation value (270000 locations in every file). In order to make a forecast for the next hour, I merge the last 8 files, which correspond to the time frame of two hours, and I add one extra column with the time of the measurements.
This is the dataset:

```
           LAT     LON    Prec
time
11:15:00  45.980  10.029    0.42  
11:15:00  45.981  10.071    0.47  
11:15:00  45.982  10.113    0.32  
11:15:00  45.984  10.155    0.30  
11:15:00  45.985  10.197    0.32  
...          ...     ...    ...    
13:00:00  29.299  33.978    0.00  
13:00:00  29.302  34.021    0.00  
13:00:00  29.304  34.064    0.00  
13:00:00  29.306  34.107    0.00  
13:00:00  29.309  34.150    0.00
```

I've used linear regression, svr and lstm, but my results are all over the place. For example, when I use linear regression it's like it doesn’t capture the motion of the phenomenon, it's basically the same as the last hour's data.
this is my code :

```py
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="X does not have valid feature names")

# Load data
df_comb = pd.read_csv('combined_files.txt', delim_whitespace=' ', dtype='unicode')

df_comb = df_comb.astype({
    'LAT': float,
    'LON': float,
    'Prec': float,
    'time': str
})

df_comb['Prec'] = df_comb['Prec'].clip(lower=0)
df_comb['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_comb['time'], format='%H%M').dt.time
df_comb = df_comb.set_index('time')

# Create lagged features for each of the 5 previous intervals
for i in range(1, 8):
    df_comb[f'Prec_lag{i}'] = df_comb['Prec'].shift(i)

# Drop the missing values introduced by lagging
df_comb = df_comb.dropna()

# Use the lagged features and location data for training
features = ['LAT', 'LON'] + [f'Prec_lag{i}' for i in range(1, 8)]
X_train = df_comb[features]
y_train = df_comb['Prec']

# Assign feature names to X_train
X_train.columns = features

# Create and fit the linear regression model
regression_model = LinearRegression()
regression_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# List to store the predictions
predictions = []

# Iterate over the locations and make predictions
for location in df_comb.groupby(['LAT', 'LON']):
    lat, lon = location[0]
    location_data = location[1]
    X_pred = location_data[features].iloc[-1].values.reshape(1, -1)
    y_pred_next_hour = regression_model.predict(X_pred)
    predictions.append({'LAT': lat, 'LON': lon, 'Predicted_Precipitation': y_pred_next_hour[0]})

# Create a DataFrame from the predictions list
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
predictions_df['Predicted_Precipitation'] = predictions_df['Predicted_Precipitation'].clip(lower=0)

# Plotting
vmin = 0
vmax = 20

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

cs = ax.tricontourf(predictions_df['LON'], predictions_df['LAT'], predictions_df['Predicted_Precipitation'], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, locator=ticker.MaxNLocator(150),
                    origin='lower',
                    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap='jet', extend='neither')

ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
cbar_vmax = np.max(predictions_df['Predicted_Precipitation'])
plt.colorbar(cs, shrink=0.5, extend='neither', ticks=np.linspace(vmin, cbar_vmax, num=7), format='%.1f')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Real data for 13:00:

[image: Img]

Real data for 13.30, this is what I was expecting after the prediction:

[image: Img]

'predicted' results:

[image: Img]

How can I solve this problem? I know that the dataset is limited for this type of prediction. But that’s what I’m asked to do.